# Why do I get 0 when dividing two numbers?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find the ratio of land area to water area but I get 0 when I try to divide the two numbers:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import math
conn = sqlite3.connect('factbook.db')
query = "SELECT SUM(area_land ) from facts WHERE area_land != '';"
query2 = "SELECT SUM(area_water) from facts WHERE area_water != '';"
area_land= pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
#print(area_land.iloc[0])
area_water= pd.read_sql_query(query2,conn)
ratio = area_land.iloc[0]/area_water.iloc[0]
print(ratio)
```

Do I have to initialize ratio to be of type float?

This is the output of the two variables:

```
SUM(area_land )    128584834                                                    
Name: 0, dtype: int64                                                           
SUM(area_water)    4633425                                                      
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Use `float(num1)/float(num2)` or `float(num1)/num2` or `num1/float(num2)` instead. Division of 2 `int` gives you another `int` in Python 2.

Comment: What are the values of  `area_land.iloc[0]` and `area_water.iloc[0]`?

Comment: @Macin I added the output in my question

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing one integer by another. When you do that, the result is delivered as an integer. For example, 1/2 = 0.5, but 0.5 expressed as an integer is 0.

Convert either or both the numerator or denominator to a *float* to have a float returned instead.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, python 3 will do the `from __future__ import division` therefore you should not get zero when dividing two integers. If it's python 2, you can add `from __future__ import division` to the top of your file, or make the column as float `area_water.your_column = area_water.your_column.astype(float)`

Answer (score 0):

You have selected the result `row` to do the division, you should use `.iloc[0,0]` to select the actual value:

```
ratio = area_land.iloc[0,0] / area_water.iloc[0,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a bit more efficient SQL approach - you can achieve your goals with a single SQL statement:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'd:/temp/test.sqlite3')
query = "select sum(coalesce(area_land,0))*1. / sum(coalesce(area_water,0))*1. as ratio" + \
        " from facts where area_land is not null or area_water is not null"

ratio = pd.read_sql(query, conn).iloc[0, 0]

print('Ratio: {}'.format(ratio))
```

Output:

```
Ratio: 0.75
```

Setup:

```
C:\sqlite3 d:\temp\test.sqlite3
create table facts(area_land int, area_water int);
insert into facts values (NULL, 10);
insert into facts values (10, NULL);
insert into facts values (5, 10);
.quit
```

Data:

```
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> .nullvalue NULL
sqlite> select * from facts;
area_land   area_water
----------  ----------
NULL        10
10          NULL
5           10
```